# latest version of ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.6 documentation that can be downloaded as a package

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentation

I know that it can be built locally and run against the yard server but I don't want to be running "yet another server locally" (YASL) :)

Is there a site that packages these together and allows them to be downloaded and be browsed locally without being on internet?

Thanks.

Bharat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost: You can get Rails 3.2.6 bundled with Ruby 1.9.2 at [railsapi.com](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.2.6_ruby-v1.9.2/rdoc.zip). If you need the latest 1.9.3 docs, checkout the latest 1.9.3 and take a look at the [sdoc github page](https://github.com/voloko/sdoc/) (the gem behind railsapi.com). It describes how to easily build the docs and merge multiple of them.

Comment: Cool!  Ruby 1.9.2 is just fine :)